# How do I get selected value in dropdown PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

I'm making a PHP Drop down inside a form to view data from a table in my database.
It shows the data correct but I dont get any output in my form action file when I submit.

It doesn't matter wich one of the outputs from the database i choose, I still get no output. It's just blank when I try to echo the output.

So how can I get the selected option in the drop down to some sort of $blabla?

Thanks

Here the code:

```
<SELECT NAME="char"> 
<option value="">Choose</option>


<?php

$qw1 = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']; 
$sql="SELECT name FROM characters WHERE account='$qw1'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
$options=""; 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$thing=$row["name"];   

  echo "<OPTION VALUE=$id>$thing</option>";
} 
?> 
</SELECT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not select `id` field:

```
$qw1 = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']; 
$sql="SELECT id, name FROM characters WHERE account='$qw1'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
$options=""; 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$id=$row["id"];   
$thing=$row["name"];   

  echo "<OPTION VALUE=$id>$thing</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear if you are using get method then use `extract($_GET);` in your action file to get all your get elements or use `extract($_POST);` for post method.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code you have to use `$_GET['name']` or `$_POST['name']` (depends on which 
method you're using inside the form tag)

```
$result = $_POSt['name'];

echo $result;
// print previous selevted value
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to modify your code like this

```
echo '<OPTION VALUE="$row['id']">$thing</option>';
```